# How should kitchen units be fitted to accommodate walls not perpendicular?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, joinery

So I got a carpenter to fit a stud wall which butts up against a brick wall of the house.  (I could've done it but I thought I'd get a pro so it was perfectly plumb and straight.)

It's all plastered with the plumbing and wiring behind, so now I assemble the kitchen units to go into the corner where the stud wall meets the house and I find it's 100 degrees rather than perpendicular!

So if I put the units flush to the walls, there's a triangular gap between them where they join, tapering out away from the wall.  Or if I screw them together at 90 degrees, the units will meet the walls in the very corner but at least one of them must come out an inch away from the wall by the time it gets a metre from the corner.

What's the best way to accommodate this?  I'm thinking I have no choice but to put the units flush to both walls and then join the worktops over the top at 100 degrees too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what 1/4 round is for 10 degrees is larger than most I have delt with bit it will hide the gap almost all homes have some areas that are not perfectly square.

Comment: And I guess it'll be ok to join the worktops at 100 degrees?